# How to change the header of a DataGrid column in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How can I change the header of a DataGrid column in code behind?

Example:

```
var dataGrid = new DataGrid();            
dataGrid.ItemsSource = someRecords;
// ... now I want to change a column header ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DataGrid.Columns:

```
   dataGrid.Columns[0].Header = "New Header for column 0";
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `DisplayName` of your binding item class as below

```
public class YourItemClass
{
    [DisplayName("Column Name")]
    public string SomeProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the header of DataGrid in `Page_Load`

```
dataGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "Any thing that you want to Enter";
```

Comment: This question is about the WPF [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx)